# neo4j transactions slowing down then throwing exception using python

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j

Running Neo 2.2.5 on a windows 10 machine with 16GB RAM, i7 cpu and a ssd drive. I am converting a mssql app to python3.5/neo. I am  connecting with py2neo (2.0.8). I am trying to run a batch load from a web api. I am pulling 200 records and batching them into Neo. The first couple batches load at the rate of 2100 statements per second. After 15 minutes, the rate is consistently down under 300/s.

My code is pretty simple:

```
graph = Graph("http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/")
graph.cypher.execute("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:Document) ASSERT d.id IS UNIQUE")
graph.cypher.execute("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (k:Keyword) ASSERT k.ui IS UNIQUE")
graph.cypher.execute("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Chemical) ASSERT c.ui IS UNIQUE")
```

Then I loop through the following statements

```
"MERGE (d:Document {id: {ID}}) ON CREATE SET d.name={NAME}, d.created={CR}, d.abstract={AB}"
"MERGE (k:Keyword  {ui: {ID}}) ON CREATE SET k.word={WORD}"
"MERGE (c:Chemical {ui: {ID}}) ON CREATE SET c.name={NAME}"
'MATCH (d:Document {id: {ID}}), (k:Keyword {ui: {UID}}) \
 MERGE (d)-[r:HAS_TOPIC]->(k)'
'MATCH (d:Document {id: {ID}}), (c:Chemical {ui: {UID}}) \
 MERGE (d)-[r:INCLUDES]->(c)'
```

---

I commit after 200 iterations of this loop. 
At the beginning I run `tx = graph.cypher.begin()`
And after 200 loops I run `tx.commit()`.

If I exit the program after one commit, the database has all of the data and everything looks good. The problems start when I let it run.

Each `tx.commit()` takes longer than the prior one, eventually I get a socket timeout error. The CPU never goes above 12% for neo-community.exe. I excluded the `default.graphdb` directory from anti-virus and there is nothing else running on the computer.

I have tried various vmoptions and the last one is:

```
-d64
-server
-Xmx2G
```

One time it exited with:

```
py2neo.cypher.error.request.InvalidFormat: Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@4440958a; line: 1, column: 679940]
```

Other times it gets past this point and exits with a socket timeout error a couple of minutes later.

I know I can batch export to a csv and use the import utility, but I want to know why it can't handle this as is.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This a "setup" operation, i.e., a one time load into an empty database? Is the `:Document` node the same for the five statements in one iteration of the loop?

Comment: are these individual statements? or all lumped together into one?

Comment: Are all equally slow or does one stand out?

Comment: The setup section is a one time run on an empty database. The loop is all run (x200) in one transaction. I have tried different batch sizes from 1-500 with the same result of a big slow down over time. I've tried commenting out :Keywords, then :Chemical on different runs and it still dramatically slows down.

Comment: Additional comments...the cpu for neo4j maxes out at 11%, I have 6 cores so it is not even maxing out one core. It stays at 11% for over 10 seconds during each commit. Interestingly, the drive has very little activity that makes out at 150kB/s.  Tried updating java to 8u60, and tried running neo 2.3M3 with no changes. MSSQL is still running at over 100k/s on the same machine and using the same drive. When I run Neo4j I stop the MSSQL service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get into an issue where Cypher merges your relationships from the wrong side. In 2.2 it sometimes is not so clever about it.

Currently for the two relationships the order is like this:

```
MATCH (d:Document {id: {ID}}), (k:Keyword {ui: {UID}}) 
MERGE (d)-[r:HAS_TOPIC]->(k)

(k)<-[:HAS_TOPIC]-(d)

MATCH (d:Document {id: {ID}}), (c:Chemical {ui: {UID}}) 
MERGE (d)-[r:INCLUDES]->(c)

(d)-[:INCLUDES]->(c)
```

So if your **keyword** in the first case or your **document** node in the second case has many relationships (or many more than the one of the other side) then it will take longer and longer.

You can work around this by changing the identifiers, e.g. to `(a)-->(b)`

The one on the left side should *always* have the fewer (or none-yet) relationships.

In 2.3 it will be more clever about this. You might want to test with the RC when it comes out soonish.

Comment: I reversed the relationship code as suggested, no difference in performance. There are only 80,000 documents and <20,000 keywords and chemicals in the db at this time. I would think with the index and unique constraint, that the performance would be much better. I am new to neo, but I think the indexes are setup right.

Comment: Can you try again with 2.3.0 ?

Comment: I posted a solution that worked on 2.2.6 and retested on 2.3 below. If it looks good, you can mark it as accepted. Once I separated the create relationship and nodes into separate transactions it added over 6000 items/sec.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I ran into the 'eager' problem as explained in:
[Mark Needham's post Neo4j: Cypher – Avoiding the Eager](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/)

I separated the relationships from the nodes and performance jumped to 6000 statements processed per second.